# Generate MSIL Code from c# without reflector/ilspy

Tags: c#, dynamic, methods, cil

I just got interested in msil opcode etc.
Normally I'm programming in C# and tried to generate Methods dynamically with Reflection.Emit / MethodBuilder but this requires opcode.

So I was intrested if it's possible to generate  Methods dynamically with parsing C# to msil and using this in the Method Builder?

So is it possible to generate methods dynamically at runtime by using reflection and C# code ?

Comment: Yes it's possible. See CodeDom, Expression Trees, etc.

Answer (score 8):

You could take a look at [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx), [`CodeDom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx), [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) etc.

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

// ...

string source = @"public static class C
                  {
                      public static void M(int i)
                      {
                          System.Console.WriteLine(""The answer is "" + i);
                      }
                  }";

Action<int> action;
using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
{
    var options = new CompilerParameters { GenerateInMemory = true };
    var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, source);
    var method = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("C").GetMethod("M");
    action = (Action<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<int>), method);
}
action(42);    // displays "The answer is 42"
```